# Multiple URL opening in MFC

Tags: windows, mfc, file-transfer

I am trying to send simultaneous request for opening URL in OpenURL() in CInternetSession class. But After sending 2 URLS requests, no other request can be send without receiving the response from previously send requests. How can I send a large number of URL request to a server and later only i want to process the response.  Please help if any other API is there for sending multiple URL request to a server and receiving the response later. I want to use in MFC windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP 1.1 specification (RFC 2068) mandates the two-connection limit.

In this way, WinInet (`CInternetSession` built on top of it) limits connections per server ([MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183110)).

You could try to invoke `SetOption` and adjust `INTERNET_OPTION_MAX_CONNS_PER_SERVER` and
 `INTERNET_OPTION_MAX_CONNS_PER_1_0_SERVER` values. ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Something like this:

```
sess.SetOption(INTERNET_OPTION_MAX_CONNS_PER_SERVER, 8); 
sess.SetOption(INTERNET_OPTION_MAX_CONNS_PER_1_0_SERVER, 8);
```